# Tower Defense: bullet math

Tags: java, math, slick2d

I am making a Tower Defense game in **Java** using the Slick2D libary.
A problem is with my bullets math. Right now the bullet will shoot after the enemies current X,Y coordinate - but since the enemy has moved when the bullet arrives at the X,Y its going to lack behind. Any idea how to fix this, other than speeding up the bullet? The bullet math is in the bottom of the bullet class.

```
public class Bullets implements GameObject {
private ArrayList<Bullet> bulletList = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
BasicTower basicTower = new BasicTower();
public Shape bulletCircle = null;
public boolean collides = false;
public int bulletCount;

public Bullets() throws SlickException {
}


@Override
public Vector2f getPosition() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame stateBasedGame) throws SlickException {
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame stateBasedGame, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    for (int i = 0; i < bulletList.size(); i++) {
        Bullet bullet = bulletList.get(i);
        bulletCircle = new Circle(bullet.location.getX(),bullet.location.getY(),10);
        if (bulletCircle.intersects( enemy.playerRectangle )){
            bulletCount++;
            bulletList.remove( i );
            collides = true;
        }else{
            collides = false;
        }
        g.setColor( red );
        g.fill(bulletCircle);
    }


}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame stateBasedGame, int delta) throws SlickException {
    //Update the bullet's position.
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    //enemy.update(gc, stateBasedGame, delta);
    for (int i = 0; i < bulletList.size(); i++) {
        Bullet bullet = bulletList.get(i);
        bullet.move();
    }
}

public void addNewBullet2(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    bulletList.add(new Bullet(x1*64+48,y1*64+48, x2, y2));
}


class Bullet {
    float startX = 0;
    float startY = 0;
    float destX = 0;
    float destY = 0;
    Point location = new Point(0, 0);
    float speed; //how fast this moves.
    float dx;
    float dy;


    public Bullet(float startX, float startY, float destX, float destY) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        location.setLocation(startX, startY);
        this.destX = destX;
        this.destY = destY;
        recalculateVector(destX, destY);
    }

    public void recalculateVector(float destX, float destY) {
        float rad = (float) (Math.atan2(destX - startX, startY - destY));
        //Can set different speeds here, if you wanted.
        speed = 5;
        this.dx = (float) Math.sin(rad) * speed;
        this.dy = -(float) Math.cos(rad) * speed;
    }

    public void move() {
        float x = location.getX();
        float y = location.getY();
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        location.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is you will have to recalculate the position at each time for your shots, so it follows its target

Comment: Can the player only click on the enemy to shoot, or do they have the ability to lead their shots?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a linear albegra problem here. You are aiming for point P0 that is where the enemies are when you start shooting them. But instead you need to point when they will be when the bullet reaches them.
So you need the enemies speed, the bullet speed, and the shooter distance to get the coordinates of the right point.

However, since math can become tricky (for example if the target doesn't follow a line) you can try to make the bullet follow the target, which of course will lead to a curve trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to take into account each enemies speed. So if you have faster or slower enemies, you adjust where the bullet gets sent using the enemies speed. Instead of just sending the bullet to the enemies X & Y, you add to the enemies X & Y based on their speed. This would send the bullet a little further in front of the enemy to compensate for the enemies speed.